# Is there a method like drawViewportToBitmapData to take a snapshot of an HTML control

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

The [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) has a method to [drawViewportToBitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#drawViewPortToBitmapData()). I need something for [mx.controls.HTML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html) component. Is there such a method?

Background:
I have a HTML  control showing a web page. I let the user type a value and the webpage is updated. If the user has scrolled the web page then I scroll to the previous scroll position. When the user makes a change, the page is rerendered. On the render event I restore the previous scroll position but there is a flicker of the top of page before it is scrolled. I'd like to show a still image until the page is completely rendered.

PS I'm using Flex and noticed there's a FlexHTMLLoader but it does not have a drawViewportToBitmapData() method either.

Comment: can't you manually do it with `BitmapData.draw`

Comment: I can and it wouldn't be too hard to do but I was hoping there was a method such as drawViewportToBitmapData already created.